# Unable to load pdo_sqlite.so extension

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to install the pdo-sqlite ext for the cli.

I have tried to run `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` and it says the ext is already up to date but when i run `php -m` it does not appear in the list.

In my /usr/lib/php/ folder I have 2 folders named 20131226 and 20160303. The latter one (20160303) contains pdo_sqlite.so but when i try to add this to the php.ini file i get the error

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: zend_fetch_resource2_ex in Unknown on line 0`

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and php 5.6.

Is anyone able to help with this problem? Also is anyone able to explain why the php extensions are stored in these different numbered folders and how php knows which one to look in? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got (at least part of) two different versions of php installed, and they're conflicting. You'll probably want to clean out the version you're not using in order to prevent further issues. It might be easiest to just wipe both and then reinstall the one you want. Also make sure that your php.ini has its `extension_dir` setting pointing to the correct directory for the version you're keeping.

The internal PHP API is versioned according to date, so when backwards-incompatible changes are made and a new version is required, you'll get a new subdirectory name. If the changes *are* backward-compatible, and no new API version is required, then you can make minor updates to your PHP version without having to recompile your extensions.

I believe 20131226 is for PHP version 5.6 and 20160303 is for PHP version 7.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! I wiped PHP completely from my system using this command: sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "` and reinstalled php and all was fine. Thank you so much for your help and very informative answer :)

Answer (score 10):

I know this question has been answered, but other people might have the same problem as I did. I hope this helps someone, because I spent three f***ing days stuck on this.

As far as I have found out, there is a faulty file in `/usr/local/lib` called `libsqlite3.so.0` which points to `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`. I renamed the file in case it was needed for something. With the command:

`cd /usr/local/lib`

`sudo mv libsqlite3.so.0 ./libsqlite3.so.0.back`

But you can also delete it:
`rm libsqlite3.so.0`

The thread that lead me to the answer: [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1505101)

This solved my problems, and I hope they solve yours as well :)

Comment: Accepted answer haven't helped me. Your answer is real good. You have saved my days. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to delete the library as mentioned in the previous comments and it worked for a short time then the problem came up again, so I did the following, when I deleted the library when doing ldd `/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite`. It appeared:

```
libsqlite3.so.0 => lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fd35803b000)
```

and that link points in the same directory to
`libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`

so replace the link in /usr/local/lib to point to this library as follows

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
```

sorry, I don't speak English so I use google translator

Answer (score 2):

you can try install php version 5 :

```
sudo apt install php5-sqlite3
```

or for another version :

PHP 7.1

```
sudo apt install php7.1-sqlite3
```

PHP 7.2

```
sudo apt install php7.2-sqlite3
```

PHP 7.3

```
sudo apt install php7.3-sqlite3
```

and another version you want....

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-sqlite3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-sqlite3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-sqlite3'

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be one of the few SO hits on `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite'`. In my case, I don't actually use sqlite, but nonetheless see this error in my Apache logs.

The problem turned out to be a CGI script that was setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (for unrelated reason) before calling PHP.  This was somehow messing up PHP, possibly making it look in the specified LD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of the system paths. Unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH before calling PHP has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, for me the issue was in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini the outcomment was removed so pdo_sqlite was loaded (or tried to) from there too.

Modules are now loaded from /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/