# PHP7.2 Sqlite3 extension is not being loaded - Debian 9

Tags: sqlite, debian, php-extension, php-7.2, debian-stretch

I tried to install php7.2-sqlite3 extension on my Debian 9, but after installation and typing `php -v` on terminal, shows me that it was unable to load dynamic library:

[image]

Pay special attention to highlighted file reference.

I tried purging my older versions of php as says in this post but didn't work:
[Unable to load pdo_sqlite.so extention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701256/unable-to-load-pdo-sqlite-so-extention)