# Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: could not find driver when trying to use a factory in my unit tests

Tags: laravel, driver, factory, phpunit

My unit tests work fine as long as I do not try to mock a DB object.  I created a Factory and am trying to use it in one of my tests. However, I keep getting `a could not find driver error`.  I have looked up a couple of stack answers and my version of php is 7.1, so not really sure what is causing the error.

Here is my testing class.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */

namespace Tests\Unit\Helper\Results;

use Jobscan\Helper\Results\FormatHelper;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Jobscan\Models\Document\Cv;
use Tests\TestCase;

class FormatHelperTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFindingsForUploadedDocxResume_whenFontTypeIsNotStandard_resultFontTypeShowsNegativeResult()
    {
        $cv = factory(Cv::class)->create([
            'content' => "Testing Test test",
        ]);
        dd($cv);



 }
}
```

In my phpunit test

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="test_db"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
 Caused by
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: could not find driver
```

database.php file

```
 // This database is ephemeral and used for testing purposes.
        'test_db' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

Comment: Are you able to use a model directly? Without a factory?

Comment: @adam nope, I tried using the model directly.

Comment: Can you show your `config/database.php` file please ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard, I just added config/database.php.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard, thanks, but now I am getting a  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' error.

Answer (score 0):

Define a setUp method in your test:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Comment: I added the setUp method and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means it doesn't find the sqlite driver within your PHP lib which means the extension is not properly loaded.
Look into your `php.ini` file (find its path by doing : `php --ini`) and find :

`extension=pdo_sqlite`

If this is written as :

`;extension=pdo_sqlite`, then you should remove the `;`.

Comment: thanks, but now I am getting a  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' error.

Comment: @Aaron this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701256/unable-to-load-pdo-sqlite-so-extention